# Having users login using facebook or create an account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

At this point users are able to login to my website using their facebook account with omniauth-facebook gem. I also want to implement a way for users to just create an account using a gem like devise, so that they can remain a bit more anonymous when posting.

Here's what I have in my sessions_controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

And then my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
include SessionsHelper

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.save!
    end
  end

  has_many :stories
end
```

Is this something I can just solve by adding in the devise gem or will I need to add a few things in my sessions_helper or user model?

Answer (score 0):

Devise has functionality built in to be able to use all of the various omniauth-* gems.  You should definitely look into it.  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview